# Problem with factorial design in Minitab

Tags: minitab, tables

I'm having a problem with a factorial design in Minitab, as it is not as clear how to proceed as all problems I've had thus far.

The problem is to create a factorial design with two factors where the first factor, Environment, which has two levels - H2O and Salt H2O whose values overlap (i.e. they cannot be differentiated by simply stating a value for low which is only met for H2O and one value for high which is only met by Salt H2O).

The second factor is Frequency and it is 10 for four measurements and 1 for four others.

The data is structured as a table such as:

```
                         Environment
                   H2O                  Salt H2O

            10    value                  value 
Frequency
```

The problem is that I don't know how to create this in Minitab. I'm aware that it will be a 2$\times$2 factorial design with 4 replicates, but as mentioned earlier I don't know how to define the Environment factor. I also don't understand how to put in the response variable.

I guess it will be the values in the table, but to what do these entries in the table correspond to in Minitab?

Comment: According to their promo video they offer free technical support and "resources to success".

Comment: The free technical support or the resources to success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's a delayed response but this could help anyone who is trying to do this:

**Follow these steps:**

Stat -> DOE -> Factorial -> Create Factorial design

Select "General Full factorial design" and select 2 in "Number of Factors"

[image]

then Click on "Design tab", Enter the factor names (Environment & Frequency) in the name boxes and enter "2" as factor as you want to have 2 levels "H2O" and "Salt H2O"

[image]

Then Click "Factors" tab and change the type as "Text" from "Numeric" using drop down menu.

Then enter the level values for two different levels as shown in the picture.

[image]

And here is the output

[image]

You can enter the response for each combination in C7 column  and proceed with further analysis. Hope this helps !